# Jenkins job configuration to trigger job only when there is a commit to particular SVN branch

Tags: jenkins, svn

Suppose there are 3 SVN branches included in my jenkins job config. And I am using poll scm to trigger the build. But, I want the build to be triggered only if a particular branch is changed out of the 3. Not using git. Any idea as to how it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Use post-commit hook for SVN.
For ubuntu OS add below script in $REPOSITORY/hooks directory

```
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
UUID=`svnlook uuid $REPOS`
/usr/bin/wget \
  --header "Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8" \
  --post-data "`svnlook changed --revision $REV $REPOS`" \
  --output-document "-" \
  --timeout=2 \
  http://server/subversion/${UUID}/notifyCommit?rev=$REV
```

for windows add below .bat in $REPOSITORY/hooks directory

```
SET REPOS=%1
SET REV=%2
SET CSCRIPT=%windir%\system32\cscript.exe
SET VBSCRIPT=C:\Repositories\post-commit-hook-jenkins.vbs
SET SVNLOOK=C:\Subversion\svnlook.exe
SET JENKINS=http://server/
"%CSCRIPT%" "%VBSCRIPT%" "%REPOS%" %2 "%SVNLOOK%" %JENKINS%
```

For more info refer below link
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin